# Select2 With Ajax Asp.net 4.0 webmethod Request

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-select2

I'm trying to drive the select2 combo box from a very simple web method (for testing only), but nothing seems to work. I've tried with static, without static - no joy.

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static String getResults(String q, String page_limit)
    {
        return "{'id':'1','text':'test'}";
    }
```

Here is the Jquery

```
$("#myHiddenField").select2({
            placeholder: "Search for item",
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            ajax: {
                url: "mypage.aspx/getResults",
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "POST",
                params: {
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                },
                quietMillis: 100,
                data: function (term, page) { 
                    return JSON.stringify({ q: term, page_limit: 10 });
                },
                results: function (data) {
                    return { results: data };
                }
            }
        });
```

I cannot for the life of me figure it out. Any thoughts or suggestions?

**EDIT**

I'm following the example for the 'SELECT2' plugin and more specifically the 'Infinite Scroll with Remote Data Section' [see here](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#doc-query) - which works fine with the example. I'm clearly missing something obvious.

Comment: What happens when you step through a debugger both in the server code and in the javascript? Is the server sending anything back; what does it look like? Tried watching what's going on in Fiddler2?

Comment: I would like to do this too.  Sadly Select2 creates a querystring and I do not think there is anything you can do about it :(

Comment: I did work around this. Post me your scenario and I'll see if I can assist. I'll also post my resolution a little later

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I was googling the problem, found this, fixed it, thought someone else googling might have the same issue.

So, to fix the problem, replace this;

```
public static String getResults(String q, String page_limit)
{
    return "{'id':'1','text':'test'}";
}
```

... with this:

```
public static String getResults(String q, String page_limit)
{
     return "[{ \"id\": \"1\", \"text\": \"test\" }]";
}
```

Also, replace this;

```
results: function (data) {
        return { results: data };
}
```

...with this:

```
 results: function (data) {
      return { results: JSON.parse(data.d) };
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ajax: {
    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/mypage.aspx/getResults") %>',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST",
    params: {
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    quietMillis: 100,
    data: function (term, page) {
        return JSON.stringify({ q: term, page_limit: 10 });
    },
    results: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        return { results: data };
    }
}
```

use: `url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/mypage.aspx/getResults") %>'`

instead of:  `url: "mypage.aspx/getResults"`

Answer (score 0):

The methods used for WebMethods should be `static`. See more details here http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/

**EDIT**

It seems that you are setting the `data` property to a function object, that is then probably serialized into a string (with the body of the function as a result maybe?) instead of setting it to a plain string.

Try changing it to something like: `data: JSON.stringify({ q: term, page_limit: 10 });`

Besides, what is the purpose of `results` property in there? I don't know about it and cannot seem to find it on jQuery's documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I did try static - it made no difference - I forgot to mention that in my original post. Apologies.